# Incorrect numbering on table broken over pages using longtabu

Tags: tables, longtable, tabu

I've a problem with table numbering when using `longtabu` and my tables go onto a second page. This was picked up by the external examiner in my viva - how embarassing!

Anyway, here's a MWE which should illustrate the issue.

I'm pretty sure it's the `\caption` command I've put in for the subsequent page headers. I included this to get the table number at the top of each page that the table is split over.

Is there a better way (correct way) of achieving the same result?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=2cm]{geometry} % sets margins
\usepackage{multirow} % allows merging of rows in tables
\usepackage{bigdelim} % Big delimiters in tables
\usepackage[margin=10pt, labelfont=bf, format=hang, textfont={small,it}]{caption} % for more interesting captions
\usepackage{rotating} % Allows rotating of figures and tables.
\usepackage{multirow} % allows merging of rows in tables
\usepackage{bigdelim} % Big delimiters in tables
\usepackage{longtable} % longtable allows tables to be split across pages
\usepackage{tabu} % Updated table environment, replaces ltablex
\usepackage{booktabs} % For professional looking tables
\usepackage{lscape} % landscape package


% Commands for use in tables
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright} % Left justification
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline} % New line command for use with \rr


\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
    \captionof{table}[Some data in a table where the numbering goes wrong.]{Some data in a table where the numbering goes wrong. }
    \begin{longtabu}{XXXXX}
        % First page header
        \toprule
        \rr \textbf{Data 1}   & \rr \textbf{Data 2} & \rr \textbf{Data 3} & \rr \textbf{Data 4} & \rr \textbf{Data 5} \tn
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    % Subsequent page header
    \caption{}[]\\
    \toprule
            \multicolumn{5}{r}{\small\sl \ldots continued from previous page} \\
        \rr \textbf{Data 1}   & \rr \textbf{Data 2} & \rr \textbf{Data 3} & \rr \textbf{Data 4} & \rr \textbf{Data 5} \tn
        \midrule
        \endhead
        % footer for all but last page of table
        \multicolumn{5}{r}{\small\sl continued on next page\ldots}\\
        \bottomrule
        \endfoot
        %footer for last page of table
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot        
    % Table data
1     & 1.1   & a     & 1     & 0.1 \\
      &       & b     & 2     & 0.2 \\
      & 1.2   & c     & 3     & 0.3 \\
      &       & d     & 4     & 0.4 \\
      & 1.3   & e     & 5     & 0.5 \\
      &       & f     & 6     & 0.6 \\
      \midrule
1     & 1.1   & a     & 1     & 0.1 \\
      &       & b     & 2     & 0.2 \\
      & 1.2   & c     & 3     & 0.3 \\
      &       & d     & 4     & 0.4 \\
      & 1.3   & e     & 5     & 0.5 \\
      &       & f     & 6     & 0.6 \\
      \midrule
1     & 1.1   & a     & 1     & 0.1 \\
      &       & b     & 2     & 0.2 \\
      & 1.2   & c     & 3     & 0.3 \\
      &       & d     & 4     & 0.4 \\
      & 1.3   & e     & 5     & 0.5 \\
      &       & f     & 6     & 0.6 \\
      \midrule
1     & 1.1   & a     & 1     & 0.1 \\
      &       & b     & 2     & 0.2 \\
      & 1.2   & c     & 3     & 0.3 \\
      &       & d     & 4     & 0.4 \\
      & 1.3   & e     & 5     & 0.5 \\
      &       & f     & 6     & 0.6 \\
      \midrule
1     & 1.1   & a     & 1     & 0.1 \\
      &       & b     & 2     & 0.2 \\
      & 1.2   & c     & 3     & 0.3 \\
      &       & d     & 4     & 0.4 \\
      & 1.3   & e     & 5     & 0.5 \\
      &       & f     & 6     & 0.6 \
    \label{tab:numbers}
    \end{longtabu}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume that longtabu operates just as longtable and that you need to include the caption inside! the longtabu environment. It implicitly says so in the docu "longtabu
is based on the longtable package which must be loaded, and all features of the longtable
environment works inside longtabu: \endhead, \endfirsthead, \endfoot, \endlastfoot and
\caption."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I realised this myself shortly before returning here to see if there were any responses. Can't remember why I started using \captionof outside of the longtabu environment. Seems a bit silly now that I think about it...

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 2):

What effect did you want to achieve? You have

```
    \caption{}[]
```

which is making an empty caption with a new number and then typesetting `[]`

Just not having this command at all would fix the problem, but if you want a non-empty caption on later pages, use `\caption[xxx]{yyy}` or `\caption*{...}` depending on what you want to happen.

Comment: Thanks David. I've just seen the error in my ways before reading your post. Using \captionof{table}{...} and then \caption{} in subsequent page headings gives the behaviour I described above. I'm trying to think now why I used \captionof outside of the longtabu environment. There must have been a reason for it but it escapes me now.

If I just use the \caption{} command for all table headers everything is fine!

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Questioner's answer (moved from question):

Problem solved (for my purposes anyway).

Using the `\captionof{table}` command outside of the `longtabu` environment seems to be the problem. If I just use `\caption{}` inside the longtabu environment all is well (see MWE below).

There must have been a good reason for me to use `\captionof` instead of `\caption`. Can't think what it was though...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=2cm]{geometry} % sets margins
\usepackage{multirow} % allows merging of rows in tables
\usepackage{bigdelim} % Big delimiters in tables
\usepackage[margin=10pt, labelfont=bf, format=hang, textfont={small,it}]{caption} % for more interesting captions
\usepackage{rotating} % Allows rotating of figures and tables.
\usepackage{multirow} % allows merging of rows in tables
\usepackage{bigdelim} % Big delimiters in tables
\usepackage{longtable} % longtable allows tables to be split across pages
\usepackage{tabu} % Updated table environment, replaces ltablex
\usepackage{booktabs} % For professional looking tables
\usepackage{lscape} % landscape package


% Commands for use in tables
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright} % Left justification
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline} % New line command for use with \rr


\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtabu}{XXXXX}
        % First page header
    % **** THIS HAS CHANGED ******
        \caption[Some data in a table where the numbering goes wrong.]{Some data in a table where the numbering goes wrong. }\\
        \toprule
        \rr \textbf{Data 1}   & \rr \textbf{Data 2} & \rr \textbf{Data 3} & \rr \textbf{Data 4} & \rr \textbf{Data 5} \tn
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    % Subsequent page header
    % **** THIS HAS CHANGED ******
        \caption{}\\
    \toprule
            \multicolumn{5}{r}{\small\sl \ldots continued from previous page} \\
        \rr \textbf{Data 1}   & \rr \textbf{Data 2} & \rr \textbf{Data 3} & \rr \textbf{Data 4} & \rr \textbf{Data 5} \tn
        \midrule
        \endhead
        % footer for all but last page of table
        \multicolumn{5}{r}{\small\sl continued on next page\ldots}\\
        \bottomrule
        \endfoot
        %footer for last page of table
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot        
    % Table data
1     & 1.1   & a     & 1     & 0.1 \\
      &       & b     & 2     & 0.2 \\
      & 1.2   & c     & 3     & 0.3 \\
      &       & d     & 4     & 0.4 \\
      & 1.3   & e     & 5     & 0.5 \\
      &       & f     & 6     & 0.6 \\
      \midrule
1     & 1.1   & a     & 1     & 0.1 \\
      &       & b     & 2     & 0.2 \\
      & 1.2   & c     & 3     & 0.3 \\
      &       & d     & 4     & 0.4 \\
      & 1.3   & e     & 5     & 0.5 \\
      &       & f     & 6     & 0.6 \\
      \midrule
1     & 1.1   & a     & 1     & 0.1 \\
      &       & b     & 2     & 0.2 \\
      & 1.2   & c     & 3     & 0.3 \\
      &       & d     & 4     & 0.4 \\
      & 1.3   & e     & 5     & 0.5 \\
      &       & f     & 6     & 0.6 \\
      \midrule
1     & 1.1   & a     & 1     & 0.1 \\
      &       & b     & 2     & 0.2 \\
      & 1.2   & c     & 3     & 0.3 \\
      &       & d     & 4     & 0.4 \\
      & 1.3   & e     & 5     & 0.5 \\
      &       & f     & 6     & 0.6 \\
      \midrule
1     & 1.1   & a     & 1     & 0.1 \\
      &       & b     & 2     & 0.2 \\
      & 1.2   & c     & 3     & 0.3 \\
      &       & d     & 4     & 0.4 \\
      & 1.3   & e     & 5     & 0.5 \\
      &       & f     & 6     & 0.6 \
    \label{tab:numbers}
    \end{longtabu}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```